# MySQL MyISAM relationship diagram

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, myisam

We're using this pretty large MySQL database with a bunch of tables. The most important table is a "plants" table, which contains about 1 million records.

This table contains about 25 fields, each and every field is a reference (not foreign key because it's MyISAM) to another table which contains the actual information. So when you look at the plants table all you get is numbers.

The issue is that I didn't write this database design, and my boss is asking me to give her a diagram of the tables relationships. As you can imagine, already with 25 fields, this becomes really complicated, and it would involve me manually going through each field, and associate it by name similarity - for example - the `category_id` field is probably a relation with the `categories` table; and so on.

Any ideas to simplify my work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the schema into [Mysql workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) (free) or [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) (paid, but IMO better) and work with that. Both have schema visualising and drawing tools that will help a lot.